# How to fold a plane?

Tags: modeling

I have a plane in Blender, and I'd like to fold it along the edges. **My goal is to fold the plane like an iPhone X's case as shown in the image:**

[image]

How to achieve this?

Comment: hello, it's not clear if you want to do it in a non destructive way as proposed by Gorgious; or simply modeled...

Comment: Bevel a scaled cube to do this.

Comment: Bare minimum is to show some effort towards your goal, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

You may stack 2 solidify modifiers with *only rim* enabled to get this kind of effect. You may also have to enable *Flip normals* and change the *offset* to get the fold in the right direction. Finally add a bevel to get rounded edges.

The modifier stack :

[image]

The base plane, and then with each consecutive modifier applied :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*I think you only can get good topology by modeling it manually...*

Start off by adding a plane (*Add > Mesh > Plane*) to the scene, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply the scale of the object. In *Edit Mode* extrude the face on the `x` or `y` axis (<kbd>E</kbd>) and delete the second face after extrusion. Select the corner edges and bevel them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Add in a [Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) and [Subdivision Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) modifier on top. Finally *right-click* the mesh in *Object Mode* and set the shading to 'smooth':

[image]

This is what you get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a plane, it may be more efficient to take a cube in the shape of the phone, and `Bevel` the edges with <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> and the mouse wheel. This will give the beveled edges smooth geometry like a curved phone would have.

Ensure that the Scale is applied to the object with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> before beveling, or you may see weird results.

Comment: I'd like the plane to be hollow, like the case, not the iPhone itself.

Comment: After beveling, you can select the topmost cube face, and delete that to obtain the hollow case. Alternatively you could extrude the 4 sides of the plane to form the sides of the case.

Answer (score 0):

To fold a flat plane, subdivide the plane to get a couple seperate boxes so you can go as thin as you want.

Then when folding a side, go to edge select and click on an edge (you only have to click on one of them) you want to fold along and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and place your cursor on selected.

Then go to face select and click on everything you want to fold. Then rotate it along the X, Y or Z axis (whichever gets the result you want) and you'll have folded one part. Then rinse and repeat.